# The test is not executed, it throws an error

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I am testing the addition of products, I want to add 10 products, for this I use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer library.

My test:

```
describe('Test products', () => {
    describe('POST /api/products/add', () => {
        it(`Should create ${addProductCount} products with 0...1000 price`, (done) => {
            let operationCount = addProductCount;
            for (let i = 0; i < addProductCount; i++) {
                let product = utils.getFakeProduct(2, 1000);
                chai
                    .request(server)
                    .post('api/products/add')
                    .set('token', constants.merchantToken)
                    .field(product)
                    .attach('product_photos', './test/path/products/test1.jpeg', 'test1.jpeg')
                    .attach('product_photos', './test/path/products/test2.jpg', 'test2.jpg')
                    .attach('product_photos', './test/path/products/test3.png', 'test3.png')
                    .end((err, res) => {
                        operationCount--;
                        expect(res).have.status(200);
                        expect(res.body).have.property('message');
                        expect(res.body.message).to.be.equal('Product added');
                        if (operationCount == 0) {
                            done();
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
    });
});

...

function getFakeProduct(lowerPrice, upperPrice) {
    let currentDate = faker.date.recent();
    let expirationDate = faker.date.recent(+1);
    let original_price = getRandomInt(lowerPrice, upperPrice);
    return {
        product_name: faker.commerce.productName(),
        product_description: `${faker.commerce.productAdjective()} ${faker.commerce.productAdjective()}`,
        original_price,
        sale_price: original_price - getRandomInt(lowerPrice, original_price - 1),
        starting_date: currentDate,
        end_date: expirationDate,
        quantity_available: faker.random.number(50),
        categories: 'HOME APPLIANCES',
    };
}
```

When performing tests, I get an error:

> TypeError: source.on is not a function
>
> at Function.DelayedStream.create (node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:33:10)
>   at FormData.CombinedStream.append (node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:44:37)
>   at FormData.append (node_modules\form-data\lib\form_data.js:74:3)
>   at Test.RequestBase.field (node_modules\superagent\lib\request-base.js:406:23)
>   at Test.RequestBase.field (node_modules\superagent\lib\request-base.js:387:12)
>   at Context.field (test/productsTest.js:53:22)
>   at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:120:23)

What is my problem? I do not use this function.

Comment: Looks like something needs to be mocked.  https://github.com/request/request-promise/issues/145

Comment: @reergymerej Sorry, I tried it and it did not help me. What could be my problem?

Comment: Try to pinpoint exactly which line is causing this.  Once you know that, Google the error and read through the issues.  It could be many things.  If you get more detail, please update here.

Comment: @reergymerej This happens after `.field (product)`, but why this happens, I can not understand

Comment: What is the value of `product`?  If you remove that line, will the test run?  A lot of these sorts off issues point to improper formdata (https://github.com/request/request/issues/1495).  That smells like it's trying to read a file, but it doesn't have a proper file ref to work with.

Comment: @reergymerej Stored the original price of the goods. He reads the photo successfully, I can’t understand the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192087/discussion-between-reergymerej-and-megaroks).

Comment: Can't help without code under test. And, you should [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), don't put everything here.